# Add other MCU to Eclipse Project wizard

Tags: eclipse, stm32, eclipse-cdt, hal

Could someone advice me, how to add an extra family devices to project wizard in Eclipse?

I've installed fresh version of Eclipse with CDT for embed. I need to work with other MCU than listed in project wizard. Maybe, you can advice me how to change the MCU later, when project will be created. I have this point now

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zM2hT.png)

I've googled for the decision, but found nothing, except using CMSIS packs from Keil.